# \u2018 includes a whitespace character under Mac OS X

Tags: macos, iterm, unicode

Regardless of whether I use the GNU version of printf--and regardless of whether I'm using the `\u2018` escape sequence in `printf` or in nodejs's `console.log`--the unicode character `‘` is always interpreted as the character with a space following it.

Any ideas on how to get this behavior to stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the problem was an option that I had set in iTerm2.  When you have the following option set for your iTerm2 profile, `\u2018` is interpreted as an ambiguous-width char and so is considered to be double-width, but since it isn't an double-width character, such as a [kanji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji), a space gets appended to it.

Just make sure that you have the following option unchecked:  [image]